# RemoteHooks with wildcards doen't work in storage container

Tags: loopbackjs, strongloop

I am using [Loopback storage service](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Storage+service) for file uploads, it works fine.
I want to do post-processing for uploaded files, so I added remote hooks methods **beforeRemote** and **afterRemote**. When i use **'*'** for method name it works. When I change it to **'upload'** or **'container.upload'** or anything else it stops working.
Even **afterSave** is not called for container.

```
module.exports = function(Container) {

 Container.beforeRemote('*.upload', function(ctx, unused, next) {
  if(ctx.req.accessToken) {
     console.log('beforeCalled with token');
   next();
  } else {
    console.log('beforeCalled no token');
    next();
  }
 });

 Container.afterRemote('*.upload', function(ctx, user, next) {
   console.log("file uploaded", user.result.files);
   next();
  });

 Container.beforeSave = function(next, modelInstance) {
  console.log("beforeSave:", modelInstance );
  next();
 };

};
```

Am I missing something ?  How it should be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around it with this for now:

```
Container.beforeRemote('**', function(ctx, unused, next) {
  if(ctx.methodString === ‘upload’) {
    ...
  }
}
```

See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/loopbackjs/EI23RYX9C9M

Comment: Update#1 `Container.afterRemote('upload',...` will work now

Comment: Update#2 For `Container.afterRemote('**', ...`, the conditional comparison string is `container.upload` now instead of `upload`

Answer (score 0):

For this particular case either `Container.beforeRemote('**.upload', function(ctx, unused, next)` or `Container.beforeRemote('upload', function(ctx, unused, next)` should be working. Would be good to get feedback from loopback developers what is the proper way though.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work, Only works with `"*"`

Comment: Which version of loopback do you have? I just tested both and they work for me.

Comment: strongloop v2.9.2 (node v0.10.33), strange that it works for you....because i was debugging it, and I found that in afterRemote handling , remotes.container._methods are empty....